# I need to enable form (it is disabled on page load) after checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I need your help here cause I am not aware of javascript or jquery library and i think i definitely have to use them in my project.I have a disabled form when the page loads and I want to enable when I checked on the check box.I tried a lot but I didn't find any solutions..

Here is the 'disable' code when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $("#form1 *").prop("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

The checkbox is :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="'.$points.'">
```

If you have any ideas please inform me!

One shot but ..no result was:

```
document.getElementById('checkbox').onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById('eksargirwsh').disabled = this.checked;
};
```

form code:

```
 <form method="post" id="eksargirwsh" action="update_points_test2.php">

           <div class="col-lg-4">
               <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                                    <h5>Form1</h5>

                                </div>
                                <div class="ibox-content">

echo '

                                    <div>
                                        <div class="feed-activity-list"><div style="border: 0.5px solid green; border-right-style:none;" class="input-group m-b"><span class="input-group-addon"> 
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="opt[]" value="'.$points.'"></span>
                                                <input type="hidden" name="opt2[]" value="'.$row_select4['id'].'">


                                          <div class="feed-element">
                                                <a href="profile.html" class="pull-left">
                                            <img alt="image" class="img-circle" src="'. $row_select4['image_url']. '">
                                                </a>
                                          <div class="media-body ">
                                         <div class="ibox-tools">
                                                        <span class="label label-primary">ΔΙΑΘΕΣΙΜΟ</span><br><br>
                                                        <span class="label label-warning-light pull-right"><strong>'  .$row_select4['points'].  '</strong> Πόντοι</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <strong>'  .$row_select4['title'].  ' </strong> '   .$row_select4['description'].  ' <br>
                                                    <small class="text-muted">Διάρκεια: <strong>'  .$row_select4['start_date'].  ' - '   .$row_select4['end_date'].  ' </strong></small>
                                                    <div class="well">
                                                        '  .$row_select4['description'].  '
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                       </div>'  ;

 <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary">SUBMIT</button> 
                          </form>
```

Comment: Is the `id="checkbox"` inside the form?

Comment: Show the code for changing disabled prop, that you have tried so far, so that we can help you.

Comment: Yes!It is inside the form!

Comment: if it is inside form, checkbox won't work because it also get disabled due to parent form. Rather take approach to disable fields using some common class to all elements. Please share your html code

Comment: The form is inside php echo cause takes data from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox is in the same form if it is  then

you have to do whole page disable except that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('form :not([type=checkbox])').prop('disabled',true);

});
```

put this function in checkbox

```
 $(":checkbox").click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
       $('#form :not([type=checkbox])').prop('disabled',false);
    }
    else{
     $('#form :not([type=checkbox])').prop('disabled',true);
    }
}) ;
```

For the User requirement Fiddle is created below is the link

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnyz6cjt/3/)

Comment: The part function doesn't work!I have put `onchange="enable_form()"` inside the input of checkbox but form isn't enabled when the checkbox is checked

Comment: $('form').prop('disabled', false); try this instead of $("form").removeAttr("disabled");

Comment: and try with onclick Two reasons why onclick is preferred over onchange.

Internet Explorer only fires the onchange event when the checkbox loses the focus (onblur). So onclick is more of a cross browser solution.
onchange happens only after the element lose focus.(You wont see a difference since you are calling alert and losing focus on every change). The pseudo code on MDC pretty much explains the element.onchange implementation.

Comment: Same again!Form isn't enabled!I use this: `function enable_form() {
              if (this.checked) {
                $('#form').prop('disabled', false);
              } else {
                $("#form :not([type=checkbox])").prop("disabled", true);
              }
            }` and `onclick="enable_form()"`

Comment: U r using id #form is the correct id can u do me a favor put it on fiddle I wil do the rest

Comment: oh!pass this from call and in function do it like function enable_form(id){ if (id.checked) {
    $("form").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("form :not([type=checkbox])").attr("disabled", true);
  } }

Comment: My first time in fiddle so forgive for any errors..(https://jsfiddle.net/platanas20/Lnyz6cjt/)

Comment: that's ok buddy hope can help

Comment: It worked man!I feel stupid and I need to learn jQuery as soon as possible.But I have one more problem if you could help me..I have 3 checkboxes but the form is enabled only with the first.I don't want this.Any ideas?

Comment: U can use id or name in not selector  like this $('#form :not("#checkbox")').prop('disabled',true);

Comment: I use this but still nothing : `$(document).ready(function() {
               $('#form :not("#checkbox")').prop('disabled',true);
        
        }); 
        
         $('#checkbox').click(function(){
            if (this.checked) {
               $('#form :not("#checkbox")').prop('disabled',false);
            }
            else{
             $('#form :not("#checkbox")').prop('disabled',true);
             
            }
        }) ;` Form is enabled only with the first checkbox and must be checked to submit.I let you know that the form is created by a php echo.Is this OK?

Comment: Yes but if the first checkbox is not checked I cannot submit the form.Whatever checkbox is checked then I can submit the form..

Comment: You want to disable all the checkboxes on load and on click of any it will enable?

Comment: i want the submit to be disabled on load and after a checkbox is checked (any of them) then I can submit the form..

Comment: I think you made it!How can I learn jQuery fast?Is there any site that can help me?

Comment: practice buddy just do the practice anything as much as you do mistake you will learn...

Comment: Good advise!Thanks a lot friend.I must buy you a present soon..Regards and be well!

Answer (score 3):

Use this. You can select elements which are not `#checkbox`, then disable them at first. Then, add a function to `checkbox` change, to enable if checked.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $("#form1 *:not(#checkbox)").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#form1").addClass('disabled');
  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    $("#form1 *:not(#checkbox)").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
    $("#form1").toggleClass('disabled', !this.checked);
  })
});
```

```
#form1{
    opacity: 1;
}
#form1.disabled{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Comment: Worked!Is it possible to put some opacity when the form is disabled?

Comment: @platanas20 Add a class to the form on such an event. Then add css to the class. If it doesn't work on `form` element, try on any parent `div`'s, or give proper css to form

Comment: The problem is that if the first checkbox isn't always checked I cannot submit the form.I don't want this cause user chooses which checkbox will be checked and he could not choose the first one